# Fedora 26 graphical login starts before network fully running

Tags: dhcp, fedora, login

I am creating a Fedora 26 image that is going to run on around 100 machines in a closed environment. These machines will be connecting to two servers, one for NFS, the other for web services. The web server also runs the DHCP server.

The services are working, save for one thing. When the client image boots the graphical login screen comes up before DHCP seems to have completed. The hostname served by DHCP does not appear on the login screen--instead it shows as "localhost.localdomain".  If a user goes to log in, the screen goes blank and then comes back with another graphical login screen. The hostname is now correct and logging in now works. If I go to another non-graphical screen by hitting Alt-F2 or Alt-F3 I can see that the hostname is correct.  The IP address is correct once logged in.

I ran a similar environment a year ago with Fedora 24 and two years ago with Fedora 22 and this problem did not happen.

I am using the classic network service (network.service) after disabling NetworkManager. I tried some of the suggestions I saw regarding sequencing (putting network-online.target in the Wants and After lists for graphical.target), but so far no success.

Any suggestions about how to resolve this problem will be appreciated!

Comment: In my system lightdm.service is after systemd-user-sessions.service which is in turn after network.target. Which DM are you using?